# Possibility to hide questions with ignored tags?

Tags: support, ignored-tags

I am wondering why questions with ignored tags are still visible and only made unclickable but still visible.

I hope there is a way of just hiding those questions instead of making them unclickable.
I think this is a duplicate but all other questions are a bit unclear.

Answer (score 4):

To plagiarize [my answer on a Movies Meta](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4465/65663):

This changed at some point and is not in preferences; now the way to hide tags rather than just gray them out is a box on the right side of the homepage:

[image: Ignored tags are just grayed out]

If you click the `Hide questions in your ignored tags` button, they will be hidden now:

[image: They are hidden now]